# How to perform image processing in ios

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiimage

I have an image named `myImage.jpg`
I have to do the following animations to the image and put the final result in an `imageView` in iOS. The requirements are:

1. Resized to 262%.
2. Duplicate layer.
3. Flip vertical.
4. Align duplicate layer to the bottom of the first layer.
5. Apply Gaussian Blur (Value - 9) to duplicate layer.
6. Move the blurred layer (duplicated layer) 47px upward
7. Added Layer mask on blurred layer.
8. Applied Gradient to mask layer from black to white.

How to do these animations on the image. I have done flip vertical using

```
- (UIImage *) flipImage: (UIImage *) image {
    UIImage *flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
    return flippedImage;
}
```

and blur with following code:

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
```

How to create a mask and gradient and how to combine these images?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. by generating separate images for original image, flipped blurred image, top and bottom gradients and combine them by using

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
```

Method.